# How to turn off "time for a break?" notifications

Tags: notification

Every hour I get a notification in the middle of my screen saying "one hour [or two or three etc) of work - time for a break?"  It comes up over what I'm trying to look at and is generally really annoying, but I haven't been able to figure out which app is doing it and how to turn it off.  Any ideas?  I'm guessing it's something really easy but I'm not getting anywhere...

Edit: Thanks for the suggestions - I'm new to Linux. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and Gnome 3.36.8.  It's not Workrave and I can't think of anything I've installed that even possibly might do it. It's a greyed out box with green text.  I'll try and get a screenshot next time it happens (it doesn't stay up long).

HAHA no wonder the mystery, it was my monitor!  An AOC gaming monitor.  I found the setting to turn it off.  Happy days.  Thanks all : )

Comment: Could this be [workrave](https://workrave.org/)?  If you go to "About Workrave", do the messages look similar?  If so, you can uninstall it...but if you didn't install it yourself, I wonder if someone else (i.e., your employer) somehow forced it on you...if so, poor you!  It's helpful for RSI prevention but it can also be annoying sometimes...

Comment: I am now on 20.04, and have used Ubuntu with Gnome 2, Unity 7, and Gnome 3, as well as some Xubuntu in the past eleven years. I have never seen a message that you describe. In other words, either some very recent Ubuntu releases invented something new, or you have installed something yourself, that does this.

Comment: `grep -ri break /etc/update-motd.d/` anything?

Comment: @nobody I tried that command and terminal accepted it but didn't give any information so I'll just have to wait a bit and see, thanks